# iOS UIDatePicker design in iOS version 8.4

Tags: ios, autolayout, uidatepicker

I have an issue with `UIDatePicker` in iOS 8.4, but the same is working in iOS 10.0 above. The issue was only on the small devices like iPhone 5s and iPhone 5.

**UIDatePicker in 8.4**

[image]

**UIDatePicker in 10.1**

[image]

Comment: You need to set your constraints properly. and make background color white for the bottom view where number of passengers and baggage are displayed.

Comment: Constraints are correct, Second image also on `iphone 5s` with `iOS 10.1`

Comment: try to set yourDatePicker.clipsToBound = true

Comment: I have tried that `clipsToBound` too, its not working, for `iOS 8.4` its taking default height as 162, but above `iOS 9.3` its changing height as like we mention.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue of UIDatePicker.

You need to set UIDatePicker background color to the white so that content behind UIDatepicker is not visible.

Below is sample code for you.

```
datePickerName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: if i set backgroundColor, i can't get exact result of second image, it will be hidding all bottom buttons and text